# Cassandra nodetool repair best practices

Tags: cassandra

This question applies to Cassandra 2.2

I am embarrassed to say that I still do not understand when I should be running a `nodetool repair`, or to be more precise on which nodes.

So far, I understand that to ensure deletes are handled correctly I should be running a **repair** at a frequency that is less than the `GC_GRACE_SECONDS`. So that's cool got that bit.

Q. If I have a cluster of 9 nodes with a replication factor of 3, what type of repair do I run? more importantly do I run the repair on **every** node, or just one node?

Q. If I have multiple data centers, does that change how I run repairs. Do I have to run them in each DC, or can it be *coordinated* from just one node in one DC?

I am hoping this is a trivial question and someone can just tell it how it is.

Comment: A question like this is likely to solicit a number of strong opinions from the community members who may favor one approach over the other. 
A general guide is to avoid such questions and rather ask a more specific question about a problem you are encountering.

Comment: Related: Gene's answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82414/do-you-have-to-run-nodetool-repair-on-every-node/172784#172784

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The nodetool repair command can be run on either a specified node **or
>   on all nodes if a node is not specified**. The node that initiates the
>   repair becomes the coordinator node for the operation.

If node it not specified it runs on all the nodes that is responsible for that partition range.

> run `nodetool repair -pr` on every node in the cluster to repair all
>   data. Otherwise, some ranges of data will not be repaired

The `nodetool repair -pr` option is good for repairs across multiple datacenters.

> **Note:** For Cassandra 2.2 and later, a recommended option for repairs across datacenters: use the -dcpar or --dc-parallel to repair
>   datacenters in parallel.

[Nodetool Repair](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesManualRepair.html)

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. `nodetool repair` is only run on the node it's being executed on. To repair all nodes, you must run it on all nodes. https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/repair-in-cassandra

Comment: Running `nodetool repair` on _Node A_ will repair all other nodes that share the same data range with _Node A_ (think: sharding). So, technically, number of nodes and the replication factor will determine which nodes you need to run them on. e.g. Only need to run on every _odd node_ for 2 replication factor. But, realistically, you may need to run it on each node in case there were some communication problems that resulted in some data was not correctly replicated.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [recommendation from datastax](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesWhen.html).

> Run repair frequently enough that every node is repaired before
>   reaching the time specified in the gc_grace_seconds setting. Deleted
>   data is properly handled in the cluster if this requirement is met.